# How to authenticate Office365 users using OAuth2.0 where username is alias?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I have a product where I have implemented OAuth2.0 for Office365. Users with their O365 accounts login into my product. For example, user1@domain.org can login into their O365 account and gets redirected to my product after the authentication is successful. I am storing their email address in my database to uniquely identify the users. Recently, one of the organization has asked their users to start using email alias to login to O365. The problem is that when authentication is successful and call gets redirected to my product, my code tries to match the username stored as user1@domain.org with the alias they have used to sign into Office365. Since there is a mismatch, my product gives an error saying there is id mismatch. I want to know if there is an API which can return a list of all alias that user is using or is there a better way to handle such situations? Any comments appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a list of all alias that user is using via [Users.aliases: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/aliases/list).

Comment: The question posted here is about Office 365 Active Directory Users and not Google users.